# Worldwide SMS Payment Gate?

Tags: sms, payment

i need to insert some SMS payment for countries British, USA and other countries.

Could You recommned to me something cheap and with sending payouts to PayPal or Bank Account in other country?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are plenty but your best choice can be daopay.com; however it charges you 1000 Euro as activation fee!
If you need a free and good one, you may try smscoin.com .
Best